# Reverse string recursive function loop

Tags: python-3.x

Where is the break criteria in this recursive function? Why doesn't this go on endlessly reversive characters of the string?

```
print('Enter your input:')
n = input()

def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]

print (reverse(n))

Enter your input:
Something
gnihtemoS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function terminates if it satisfies two properties:

- There must be a "base case" which is solved without any recursive calls, and
- Each recursive call must be on an input which is "closer" to the base case than before.

In this recursive function, the base case is the empty string; it is handled by `return s` without making any recursive calls. The recursive call is on the string `s[1:]` which is one character shorter than `s`, so it is "closer" to the empty string. Therefore the function satisfies both of these properties, so it always terminates.

Answer (score 1):

When the String is of length 0, you make a non-recursive return, causing the recursive calls on the stack to return until you get all the way to the bottom of them.